# How to make snake's body parts follow each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a variation of the "Snake" game. Segments1 is a list containg the snake's body parts

This piece of code works fine in making the first part of the body follow the head

```
        if len(segments1) > 0:
            x = player1.xcor()
            y = player1.ycor()
            segments1[0].goto(x,y)
```

But the rest of my code, which is supposed to make the other body parts follow the first body part, just stacks the body parts on top each other

```
        for index in range(len(segments1)):
            if index > 0:
                x = segments1[index-1].xcor()
                y = segments1[index-1].ycor()
                segments1[index].goto(x,y)
```

[image]

Image shows snake after eating two pieces of food, black being the head, one grey body part a little behind it and another grey body part stacked on top

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong algorithm.  Since each body part follows the one in front, then the net effect is to simply make the end segment go away.

```
segments[-1].del
```

Comment: I love this answer, the only issue is that either the snakes gets progressively shorter, or a new "head" segment needs to be created every move ultimately making the segments snake through memory as well as in the game.

Comment: Yes, then you create or delete as needed.  Doing so is not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is that each segment is set the to prior segment's location. I guess the assumption is that `player1` is the `head`, but conceptually the `head` could also be the "first" `segment` and in that case `prior_position` would be set to where ever the `head` was expected next.

```
prior_position = (player1.xcor(), player1.ycor())
for segment in segments1:
    current_position = (segment.xcor(), segment.ycor())
    segment.goto(**prior_position)
    prior_position = current_position
```